# Kivy: How to reliably set [keyboard] focus on-mouse-down

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to assign focus to a widget when it's clicked. I am only partially successful in doing so.

### Attempt 1:

```
class TreeWidget(Widget, FocusBehavior):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ret = super(TreeWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)

        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return ret

        self.focus = True

        # ...

        return ret
```

This sets the focus to the widget for the brief moment between mouse-down and mouse-up.

### Attempt 2:

Attempt 2 was to add the below code below; this doesn't help in any (visible) way; i.e. after releasing the mouse my widget still has no focus.

```
class ...

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.focus = True

        ret = super(TreeWidget, self).on_touch_up(touch)
        return ret  
        return True #  (attempt 2b, also unsuccessful)
```

### Attempt 3:

```
class TreeWidget(Widget, FocusBehavior):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ret = super(TreeWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)

        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return ret

        touch.grab(self)

        self.focus = True

        # ...

        return ret

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        # Taken from the docs: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#grabbing-touch-events
        if touch.grab_current is self:

            # ok, the current touch is dispatched for us.
            # do something interesting here
            print('Hello world!')
            self.focus = True

            # don't forget to ungrab ourself, or you might have side effects
            touch.ungrab(self)

            # and accept the last up
            return True
```

Although this solution works, I don't understand why. This means I'm sure to run into a related problem very soon. Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong (or right). In particular, what's causing the loss of focus on mouse up (in all the solutions) and why isn't this repaired in solution 2?

Context: a desktop application on Kivy v1.9.1, Python v3.4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is the ordering of the superclasses:

Changing the very first line of the first attempt like so fixes the problem:

```
class TreeWidget(FocusBehavior, Widget):
```

---

With help of discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/MrKU4-F0wpU

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **unfocus_on_touch** widget property to **False**

```
class Attempt1(Attempt):

def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    ret = super(Attempt1, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        return ret

    self.unfocus_on_touch = False
    self.focus = True
    return ret
```